# How to pass session value in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I want to pass $var variable with session to a page . And want to receive this data.

```
public function check(Request $request)
{
    $c_email = $request->email;
    $c_pass=$request->pass;
    $c_type=$request->select;
    //dd($Idpass);
   $var=DB::select("SELECT * FROM reg where email = '$c_email' and Password = '$c_pass' and type = '$c_type'");
   if ($var) {
       session_start();
       $request->session()->put('key', '$var');
     return redirect('farmer');
   }
   else {
    $msg="Invalid login";
    return view('index')->with('show',$msg);
   }
}
```

Comment: I think flash is more useful in your case. Why? It's because, if you refresh the site. Laravel will automatically destroy the session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is data isn't persisting when you're redirecting, so you need to [use `with()` with `redirect()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data):

```
return redirect('farmer')->with('key', $var);
```

In a view:

```
session('key')
```

Also, you don't need to use `session_start()` to work with session data.

Comment: Thanks. It's working. Another issue is $var is a array variable . I also use foreach but i cannot receive a particular field . @foreach($us as $va) {{$va->name}} @endforeach

Answer (score 1):

**To put the session**

```
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');
```

**Passing value to the view part**

```
return redirect('farmer')->with('sometext',$var);
```

**In view part check the session has value**

```
if ($request->session()->has('users')) {
// your code
}
```

**Getting Session value**

```
$value = $request->session()->get('key', 'default');
```

Comment: It is ok. but I want to show session value. here $var contains multiple data from database. My database table fields are name,email,phone.
 Thanks

Comment: just get your value using : $value = $request->session()->get('key', 'default'); and show it {{$value}} like this.